# The close options dialog box and closing questions from the queue

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, close-dialog, flag-dashboard

## Bug - Closing questions from the queue

The close question dialog appears below the flag box. It would be better to have it over the flagged post box.

Example:

[image]
[image]

On a web browser, large screen.

Comment: When I try, it opens in the center of the screen like it does on question pages.  I am, however, seeing a z-index but when the post has previously been visited and the mouse is outside.

Comment: @BrianNickel hm it must be userscripts. I'll have to sort out which one it is. Also that red dot is always there. What do you mean you see a z-index?

Comment: `z-index` is the layering system inside web pages that controls what's on top of what, and it can be wildly complicated.  Being behind that red dot is part of the problem.  I'm on a separate project that will refresh this dialog, so I think the fix will get rolled into that project.

Comment: @BrianNickel yeh I understand what a z index is. I was wondering what you were seeing.

Comment: When a post has been previously visited, it gets a light opacity when not hovered or focused. Since the modal is a child of the flagged post, it is subject to this treatment. At least in Safari, if I click on “Close” then mouse away, the flag and the dialog fade. This shifts the dialog to another z-index where it gets obscured by the next flagged post.

Comment: @BrianNickel ah that sounds familiar. There's a lot of little hiccups. Overall it's very good. I notice a lot of things, as I've handled thousands of flags. I need to take the time to determine how the userscripts are affecting the UI